# How many ways to make change for an amount using a specific number of coins

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

assume you have coins with face value "1", "4", and "8".
How many ways are there to make change for a given amount X, using exactly Z coins in total?

my initial idea was to use generating functions, e.g.

$$ 1*a + 4*b + 8*c = X$$
  $$a+b+c = Z$$

so

$$a = Z-b-c$$
  $$1*(Z-b-c) + 4*b + 8*c = N$$
  $$3b + 7c = N-Z$$

The total number of integer solutions of which (ignoring Z - the shift could be applied later on) I believe could be expressed via a power series as

$$\frac{1}{(1-x^3)(1-x^7)}$$

unfortunately, this doesn't have any non-negativity constraint for a though, so would include impossible combinations (a negative amount of coin 1).

Is there any way to express this problem in a generating function that takes this constraint into account? Is there maybe even a more elegant way to solve the underlying question, without generating functions at all?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you found an example of a value $X$ with two different triples that satisfy your  requirements?  Given a triple $(a,b,c)$ that works, can you describe a way to modify it to get a new one?

Comment: @lulu Let's say X=7, Z=3 (reaching amount 7 with 3 coins). There's no way to do this, so valid combinations should be = 0. But above equation would recognize (-1;2;0) as a valid triple and hence give 1 combination instead of 0.

Comment: Not sure what your point is.  I am asking:  if I hand you a triple $(a,b,c)$ with $a+b+c=X$ and $a+4b+8c=Z$ can you produce a different one that also satisfies those two equations?  Of course, it has to be an "admissible" triple, with all terms $≥0$.  What's the smallest $X$ for which two such triples exist?

Comment: @lulu If $X=28,Z=7$ we have two solutions $(a,b,c)=(4,0,3),(0,7,0).$ I think this is a kind of basis for multiple solutions, that is, $X=28t,Z=7t$ has $t+1$ solutions, patching together some of each of the above triples (including all triples of one or the other type).

Comment: @coffeemath  Exactly.  if $(a,b,c)$ is a solution then so is $(a+3n,b-7n,c+4n)$ and these are all the solutions.  Of course you need to start somewhere but we can use the fact that $3\times 5+7\times (-2)=1$ to get a solution (which may have negative entries) and build all possible solutions from there.  I doubt there is a sensible closed formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use linear algebra. If we take the matrix

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 4 & 8 \\ 1 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
we want to solve
$$Ax = \begin{pmatrix}X \\ Z\end{pmatrix}.$$

Now if this system has a solution at all, then the set of all solutions is described by the kernel of $A$. This kernel has dimension one (over $\mathbb{Q}$, for example), so there is a vector $v \in \mathbb{Q}^3$ such that every solution has the form $x_0 + rv$ with $r \in \mathbb{Q}$, where $x_0$ is an abitrary solution. Can you compute $v$? Can you find a vector $v$ only containing integers and, if possible, coprime ones?

This vector is what lulu was asking for in the comments: How to change one valid solution to another one.

Now assume we have one solution $(a,b,c)$. We can chose $r \in \mathbb{Q}$ to get all rational solutions as $(a,b,c) + rv$. As both $(a,b,c)$ and $v$ are integer vectors, with the entries of $v$ being coprime, and we also want integer solutions, we get them all by chosing $r \in \mathbb{Z}$.

This allows you to enumerate all integer solutions. Then all that is left is checking which of them have all three entries non-negative. The actual counting depends on $N$ and $Z$, of course. If you are looking for a closed formula that works for all $N$ and $Z$, I'm not sure if that is easy/possible (but I wouldn't mind being proven wrong on that, of course).

Comment: Thanks, this is very interesting! I am indeed looking for the most efficient solution. So closed form solutions would be ideal, though as you say, I'm not at all sure such a thing exists at all. (I'll mark yours as the answer in a day or two if nobody buds in with ideas for a closed form approach :) )